# Does the Validation Application Block in Entlib 5.0 support client-side validation?

Tags: .net, enterprise-library, application-blocks

VAB used to be just server-side bur does the new version of Entlib allow client-side validation for VAB?

Answer (score 0):

VAB is for the server-side only.  The architecture of the block is intended to be used more in a Business Logic layer or Data layer and can be used by Winform applications as well as ASP.NET apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VAB on the client-side as well. Take a look at the "User Interface Validation Integration" section at the end of the [this chapter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/agile/archive/2010/11/15/validation-application-block-for-silverlight-open-question.aspx).

Also, we are building [support for client-side validation in Silverlight](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/agile/archive/2010/11/15/validation-application-block-for-silverlight-open-question.aspx) as you can see from [this top-rated story](http://entlib.uservoice.com/forums/90505-silverlight-integration-pack/suggestions/1284621-validating-the-same-data-in-different-layers-of-an?ref=title) on our backlog.

Comment: Update: for those interested in Silverlight validation with Enterprise Library, we've already ported VAB to Silverlight. See this demo http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Enterprise-Library-for-Silverlight-Validation-demo and this one: http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Enterprise-Library-for-Silverlight-Cross-tier-validation-demo